# How to change LIBGDX default game app name?

Tags: android, libgdx

I am working on android game development, whenever i test my game on my device, it is installed with the name "My LIBGDX Game", how can I change it?

Comment: Open AndroidManifest.xml and change the name there to whatever you want

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To change your app name, you simply need to change the value of the `android:label` attribute in the `<application>` tag of your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

This attribute usually references a string in `strings.xml` which you can edit.